# How can ? match next line by preg_match in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-match

How can I match next line in string by `preg_match`?
I have tried, the code is below.

```
$str = "== heading ==
   strint1...
   strint2...
   strint3...
   strint4...";

preg_match_all("/==\sheading\s==((?:.|[\r\n])+)/i",$str,$res);
```

Most of the time its working fine, But sometime its not working( the page is just loading only ).

Comment: Use `\v` (any vertical whitespace character) after `==`.

Comment: I tired , But the same problem i am facing. I am getting the error apache related like " apache http server has stopped working "

Comment: Strange. What output do you wish to get?

Comment: i want to get all string under the " == heading == "

Comment: In Regex Coach i tried your version and works for me so its strange. Try this: preg_match("/==\sheading\s==([^$]+)/is", $str, $res);

Comment: @StudioArena thank you so much :) .... now working. may i know the meaning of " /is ".

Comment: S = If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. 
In my regular expression above i don't think S has any speacial meaning but usually i use it :) But in your regular expression maybe S do the job.

Comment: .. and I is of course for case insensitive or I = If this modifier is set, letters in the pattern match both upper and lower case letters. 
You can set more than one modifier like in example above /is or just /i or /s etc.